# What does the notice "Post is related to a rapidly changing event." mean?

Tags: discussion

I just saw [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86458/21267) which has the following notice applied to it:

> Post is related to a rapidly changing event.

[image]

**What does this notice mean?**

Who can place/remove these notices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a notice **placed by a moderator** which means that this post is likely to change rapidly based on on-going real-world event(s).

> Yes, it's a post notice that moderators can put on a question / answer. The idea is to give heads-up to visitors that information contained therein may change over a short period of time.
>   Naturally, any answer can change in correctness over time, but with things such as safety in a country due to civil unrest et al I felt it was a good use of the post notice to notify viewers of the situation.
>   PS - It's not a flag, it's a post notice.
> <sup>*-[Ankur Banerjee ♦](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/108/ankur-banerjee) on [Travel SE (Meta)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1500/13872).*</sup>

For more information, see: [**What does the “Current event” post notice mean?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107269/252593)